# Measuring tool and field calculator giving wrong area in QGIS 3.10.4

Tags: coordinate-system, area, measurements

I've been consistently having issues with the QGIS measuring tool in 3.10.4. When I measure an area or line (regardless of the units) it gives a wrong value when compared to the measuring tool in Google Earth. This also applies when using the `$area` in field calculator. I am guessing this is a CRS issue, possibly related to the base map. I am using EPSG 27700 (British National Grid) and all my layers are also set to this.

The base map I am using is a Google aerial from QuickMapServices plugin, which I have manually set to convert to EPSG 27700 as otherwise it shows up somewhere completely else. If anyone has any ideas that would be really helpful, as I've tried to fix myself to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "which I have manually set to convert to EPSG 27700 as otherwise it shows up somewhere completely else"? Usually, QMS layers insist on being in epsg:3857

Comment: so maybe this is where the issue is coming in... so if I remove the base layer and reload from scratch (presumably in EPSG 3857 as you say) it shows all my mapped layers as being I think somewhere off the coast of Africa (as if the coordinates were reversed I think, as they should be in the UK). I'm not sure why this would be happening? Its a bit tricky to see exactly where QGIS is mapping them to as when you try and zoom out it crashes (I think because it is trying to get the base map for a larger area)

Comment: your base data is almost certainly not in 27700 but could be in 4326. can you [edit] your question with details of your data, ideally the ogrinfo output or qgis properties of it

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by the ogrinfo or QGIS properties exactly, would you be able to tell me how to get this or attach it?